# How to write react / angular micro application that share the route based on redux?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

Writing micro-services on back-end is not that much confusing, specially if we are building api endpoints. We can write separate project for users management, separate project for reporting, ..., and combine all their endpoint with AWS gateway api, or for smaller one acomplish this with nginx reverse proxy to provide a integrated api service.

The way I am suggesting the team for writing back-end is something like that:

localhost:8001/list **<- reverse proxy to ->** apiproxy.com/users/list

localhost:8003/transaction **<- reverse proxy to ->** apiproxy.com/transactions/create

So it seems simple, we write our projects by category in separate repos, and each team/person can work individualy on it. But here goes my question:

" How can we implement a solution, that a server rendered React app ( Or, angular, Vue ) can render, and developed with separate repositories, but in build time, they merge into each other, and their routing works well."

So, in this senario, each repository must be able to bootstrap independetly. The aim is not create a new framework.

Does anyone has any kind of suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Canopy Tax, a tech startup based in Utah that builds solutions for tax professionals, faced a similar situation about 2 years ago. They wanted to be able to implement some sort of microservice architecture in the front end, and guess what, they succeeded. The solution is not perfect yet, there's a lot of trade offs, but the objective is met and they are using this in production with their customers. I have seen it in action at some meet ups they have hosted.

Canopy Tax open sourced their framework last year, it is called Sofe. [Here it is the link to the github project](https://github.com/CanopyTax/sofe). Their solution, is used in production and is here to stay for a long time. They recently raised another [20 million](https://www.canopytax.com/blog/canopy-raises-20m-round-modernize-experience-tax-professionals-clients/) in VC this year.

This sofe framework is what they call a Meta-framework. It is basically a main router that decides where to dispatch your routes. Then it dispatches to an angular, ember, react, angular2 app. And it gets even better, in the same page you can have pieces built in react, pieces in angular, etc. You get the idea. This allowed them to scale faster, get more talent as well as they are no longer limited to just one framework. And they can deploy anytime and their teams (squads) don't depend on each other as those pieces of the app are independent applications, like microservices in the front end.

It is still fairly new but definitively worth a look. I recently talked with them at a meet up and some other companies are using this as well in production. They also have an inspector tool an other tools that show you what framework that piece of the web app you select belongs to (e.g. react, angular, etc). [Here it is the live demo of sofe in action.](https://single-spa.surge.sh/)

Click on framework inspector there, then turn it on. It will show you.

There's trade offs on this approach, one is that this is not supported yet for mobile. It works great for their product but they are working on solutions for that as well.

Disclaimer: I do not work at Canopy Tax, I have never worked there and I do not have any relation with the company. I just like Sofe and what they are doing with the project.

Comment: Their current version is stable enough for production use they haven't updated since Dec 2016 and their branch named 2.0 was last updated on April 26th 2017 (about 40 days ago).